# Pymc3 multi-dimensional variable equation

Tags: python, theano, bayesian, pymc3

I am trying to use multi-dimensional variables in pymc3 to describe a system of 4 variables that share a common factor. Perhaps I am thinking about this wrong, but when I setup the model I continually get errors from pymc3 about input dimension mismatch. I have tried several variations to no avail. How can I use pymc3's shape argument to describe a system of 4 observed variables with a structure that shares a common observed variable?

```
import pymc3
import numpy

# Simulate some data
shared_obs = numpy.random.normal(0., 0.25, 1000)
indiv_obs = numpy.random.normal(0.1, 0.5, 1000)

# Build a model
with pymc3.Model():
    shared_mu = pymc3.Uniform('shared_mu', -0.5, 0.5)
    shared_sigma = pymc3.Lognormal('shared_sigma', 0.1, 1.)
    shared = pymc3.Normal('shared', mu=shared_mu, sd=shared_sigma, observed=shared_obs)
    a = pymc3.Uniform('a', -1., 1., shape=4)
    B = pymc3.Uniform('B', -1., 1., shape=4)
    sigma = pymc3.Lognormal('sigma', 0.1, 1., shape=4)
    indiv = pymc3.Normal('indiv', mu=a + B*shared, sd = sigma, observed=indiv_obs, shape=4)
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         6     B = pymc3.Uniform('B', -1., 1., shape=4)
>         7     sigma = pymc3.Lognormal('sigma', 0.1, 1., shape=4)
>   ----> 8     indiv = pymc3.Normal('indiv', mu=a + B*shared, sd = sigma, observed=indiv_obs, shape=4)
>
> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\var.py in
>   **mul**(self, other)
>       160         # and the return value in that case
>       161         try:
>   --> 162             return theano.tensor.mul(self, other)
>       163         except (NotImplementedError, AsTensorError):
>       164             return NotImplemented
>
> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py in
>   **call**(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
>       666                 thunk.outputs = [storage_map[v] for v in node.outputs]
>       667 
>   --> 668                 required = thunk()
>       669                 assert not required  # We provided all inputs
>       670
>
> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py in
>   rval()
>       881 
>       882         def rval():
>   --> 883             fill_storage()
>       884             for o in node.outputs:
>       885                 compute_map[o][0] = True
>
> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py in
>   **call**(self)    1705                 print(self.error_storage, file=sys.stderr)    1706                 raise
>   -> 1707             reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)    1708     1709
>
> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp,
>   value, tb)
>       684         if value.**traceback** is not tb:
>       685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>   --> 686         raise value
>       687 
>       688 else:
>
> ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[0] = 4,
>   input[1].shape[0] = 1000)

Comment: Why is `shared` an observed variable? That is a bit unusual. The error message tells you, that you can't multiply `B * shared`, which is expected. `B` has shape (4,) and `shared` has shape `(1000,)`.

Comment: I agree that the matrix multiplication doesn't really make sense; but, I can't seem to express the multiplication appropriately; I was thinking (4,) ~ (4,1) and I've experimented with using ".T" for either and both variables to no avail. I guess I'm trying to get to a (1000,4) or vice-versa matrix. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`*` is element-wise multiplication. If you want the outer product you can use

```
B[None, :] * shared[:, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar to work by using `theano.shared.stack()`. Basically, I stacked a bunch of copies of my data (making sure to set the axis right) and then multiplied by the parameters I needed. My command was

```
mu_alphas = pm.Normal('mu_alphas', 0, 5, shape=3)
mu_betas = pm.Normal('mu_betas', 0, 5, shape=3)
mu = pm.Deterministic('mu', mu_alphas + mu_betas * tt.stack([df.x, df.x, df.x], axis=1))
```

where `df.x is (1000,)`. Hope something similar can work for you.